# Console warning from antd table. Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, console, components, warnings, antd

Observing the below warning in the console. On debugging it is observed that the warning is coming from antd table component.

[image]

All the code is attached below.

> Table Component

```
 <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={dataSource}
  />
```

> dataSource

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    id: "1",
    todo: "todo-1",
    description: "description-1",
    status: false
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    todo: "todo-2",
    description: "description-2",
    status: true
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    todo: "todo-3",
    description: "description-3",
    status: false
  }
];
```

> columns

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Todo",
    dataIndex: "todo",
    key: "todo"
  },
  {
    title: "Description",
    dataIndex: "description",
    key: "description"
  },
  {
    title: "Status",
    dataIndex: "status",
    key: "status",
    render: (tag) => (
      <>
        <Tag color={tag ? "green" : "red"}>{tag ? "Done" : "Pending"}</Tag>
      </>
    )
  }
];
```

Answer (score 5):

### 2 ways of doing this!

The warning is because every row(todo) in `dataSource` didn't have a unique property `key`.

You can fix this by choosing one of the following ways.

1. Add a property `key` with a unique value for every object in the array dataSource.
2. Here in the dataSource the property `id` seems to be unique for each row.
   You need to make the table component consider the `id` property for identifying a specific row uniquely.

You can do this by passing a rowKey prop to the Table Component.

```
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    rowKey={(record) => record.id}
  />
```

Note: Here `id` is unique. So the code is as above. If in case the unique value is with another key `index` then you need to change the code accordingly. (as below)

```
rowKey={(record) => record.index}
```

Answer (score 0):

3rd way of doing this (if you don't have an id or index property):

```
datasource={props.data}
rowKey={record => props.data.indexOf(record)}
```

where prop.data is an array.